# Is there a working CPAN/CPAN6 like project for Perl 6?

Tags: cpan, raku

I'm playing around with Rakudo Perl 6 lately and was searching for a project similar to CPAN. I found CPAN 6, but I think there is no Perl 6 code yet.

So I'm looking for some alternative that does not necessarily aim to be a long term solution, but is capable of maintaining modules and is written in Perl 6.

As Rakudo development goes it might be possible to create more complex Perl 6 code soon.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your first stop for Perl 6 modules should be https://modules.raku.org/.

Modules should be installed with [zef](https://github.com/ugexe/zef).

Answer (score 20):

Markov owns [cpan6.org](http://cpan6.org/) and worked on-and-off for some years on it. Most people I've talked don't regard this project well for various reasons. Most existing Perl 6 code lives at [modules.raku.org](http://modules.raku.org/), formerly proto.perl.org.

There's been talk on `cpan-workers` to simply extend the archive structure in some canonical way to make it more suitable for other languages, a [solution](https://rakudo.party/post/CPAN6-Is-Here) arrived 7 years later.

Answer (score 8):

The new hotness is [zef](https://github.com/ugexe/zef). This will query [modules](http://modules.perl6.org) available on the Perl 6 website. It comes with the latest version of [Rakudo *](http://rakudo.org/how-to-get-rakudo/) and is very simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, March 2018, [`zef`](https://github.com/ugexe/zef) is the preferred way of installing Perl 6 modules and it taps two different repositories, [the list of modules in modules.perl.org](https://modules.perl.org) and, effectively, [CPAN](https://search.cpan.org), which will eventually become the only place for Perl 6 modules.